# How can I create an object that only has a value if some condition is met?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to put an if statement inside an object but I am not sure if it is possible.

Here is what I am aiming for.

```
function typed(){
    $(".code-animate").typed({
        strings: options.typed.strings,
        typeSpeed: options.typed.typeSpeed,
        backSpeed: options.typed.backSpeed,
        contentType: 'text',
        loop: true,
        if(options.typed.callback)callback: options.typed.callback // this is what I am trying to do
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want:

Ternary operator:

```
var foo = {
    callback: someValue ? someValue : null
}
```

OR operator (tends to be more elegant than ternary in most simple cases):

```
var foo = {
    callback: someValue || null
}
```

Post object creation insertion:

```
var foo = {};
if (someValue) foo.callback = someValue;
```

Notice that in the two first cases, your object will always have a member called "callback". It will have a `null` value if the condition is not met. In the last case, if the condition is not met, your object will not have a member called "callback". You may force your object to have a "callback" with a null value by using an `else` statement, if that's convenient for you.

Comment: thanks for the examples, unfortunately I cannot pass `null` as I have no control over what `callback:`  accepts. I can only pass the value it is expecting or not set it at all

Comment: Then the third example is the one you need.

Answer (score 4):

You can always pull it outside:

```
var opts = {
    strings: options.typed.strings,
    typeSpeed: options.typed.typeSpeed,
    backSpeed: options.typed.backSpeed,
    contentType: 'text',
    loop: true,
}
if(options.typed.callback)
    opts.callback = options.typed.callback
$(".code-animate").typed(opts);
```

Comment: "You can alwyas pull it outside" That's what she said

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to use ternary operator instead of `if`, this is the way:

```
Object.assign(
    {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
    }, 
    cond ? {key3: value3} : {}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build the object first, then use this in the typed function:

```
var params = {
    strings: options.typed.strings,
    typeSpeed: options.typed.typeSpeed,
    backSpeed: options.typed.backSpeed,
    contentType: 'text',
    loop: true,
}

if( something == true ) { params.test = 'qwerty'; }

$(".code-animate").typed(params);
```